# Google Chrome Browser Block ".AspNetCore.Identity.Application" Cookie In Deployment Only

Tags: authentication, iis, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

After deploy asp.net core mvc 6 to iis server the user in case submit a true login not redirected to the controller and not authenticated, when I tracked the cookie in developer tools there is a ! mark on `.AspNetCore.Identity.Application` and when hover on it there is a message show (This cookie was blocked because it had the "Secure" attribute and the connection was not secure).

What I tried Before

- Changing the cookie configuration
- Exchange return `LocalRedirect(returnUrl)` To return `RedirectionToAction("Index","Home")`
- Add `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute on `LoginModel` in `Areas.Identity.Pages.Account`
- Remove `Use.HttpsRedirection();` from program.cs

Answer (score 1):

Because there are many apps host in the server so the browser blocked the cookie cause the other apps have the same cookie name which `.AspNetCore.Identity.Application`. So simply the issue can be solved by changing the name of the cookie:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options => 
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
});

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => options.Cookie.Name = "AppNameForExample");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your cookies are configured to require an HTTPS connection. When you try to set them on a non-secure connection, they will be rejected. You can try these steps:

1. Obtain a valid SSL certificate: You'll need a certificate that is trusted by the browsers you're targeting. Check your **web.config** file settings for:

```
<httpCookies requireSSL="true" />
```

2. Configure IIS to use HTTPS: This involves binding the SSL certificate to the IIS website and enabling HTTPS.
3. Update your ASP.NET Core application to use HTTPS: In the Startup.cs file, you can use the following code to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite;

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    var options = new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToHttps();
    app.UseRewriter(options);

    // rest of the code...
}
```